# Union of a vector subspace and a non-subspace

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

I had a question. Suppose you have a vector space V. And suppose $U_1$ is a subspace and $U_2$ is a subset of $V$ but it is not a subspace. If $U_1\cup U_2$ is a subspace then is $U_2\subseteq U_1$?

Comment: Hint: What if $U_2$ was the complement of $U_1$ in $V$ (as a set)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building off of Tobias' comment, let $U_1\subset U\subset V$ be a chain of subspaces of $V$ and let $U_2=U\setminus U_1$. Then $U_2$ is not a subspace since $\mathbf 0\notin U_2$. However,
$$
U_1\cup U_2=U
$$
so $U_1\cup U_2$ is a subspace.

To visualize this we could take $V=\Bbb R^3$, $U$ the $xy$-plane, and $U_1$ the $x$-axis. Then $U_2$ is the $xy$-plane with the $x$-axis deleted and $U_1\cup U_2$ is the whole $xy$-plane.